# How to prevent media URL from being plagiarized?

Tags: android, encryption, android-mediaplayer, media-player, exoplayer

I have an application which will provide some exclusive **media contents (Audio/Video)** to the subscribed customers.

In order to do that, I will fetch contents from the server, which are stored previously from admin panel. Server will send me a response containing the corresponding URL of a particular content (ex: video).

I want to keep that URL secret by any means (through encryption or something). As there are many possibilities to decompose my app & *if anyone hit the URL, one can easily make copy of the video.*

There is an option to use user authentication (through token or Firebase Auth). But a valid user (who also appeared to be a hacker) can also make copy of my private contents, right?

So, I don't want to use the URL directly. Is there any way to play encrypted media contents? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What you need to do is *secure the url*, not try to keep it secret.

Comment: Sir, how can make the URL secure? Some hints will do nicely.

Comment: Require a login or some other kind of credential verification.  There are several ways to do that.

Comment: And, after the user is authenticated, you can return a URL that is good for a single use or otherwise time-limited.

Comment: @JamesKPolk If I use a time-related system, let us assume we give 1 hour before changing a particular token for a single user. He can retrieve the user token when he logs in, then use the same token within an hour to hit the video link. If he can open the link in a browser, he can certainly make copies. Pardon me If I fail to understand, Sir.

Comment: You really need to be looking at Android support for DRM, but I don't know much about that. You might start [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary).

Comment: @noob-Sci-Bot so -do you want let users to play the content, but not be able to save it?

Comment: @gusto2 Yes, exactly.